# Async methods and progress indicator

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, progress-bar

I have a silverlight application which is making multiple async calls:

The problem I am facing is to how to determine if all the async calls are finished so that I can stop displaying the progress indicator. In the example below, progress indicator is stopped as soon as the first async method returns.

Any tips on how to resolve this ?

```
Constructor()
{
   startprogressindicator();
   callasync1(finished1);
   callasync2(finished2);
   //.... and so on

}

public void finished1()
{
    stopprogressindicator();

}

public void finished2()
{
    stopprogressindicator();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to asynchronously wait for both methods to finish, currently you call `stopprogressindicator` as soon as any of the method completes.

Refactor your code to return `Task` from `callasync1` and `callasync2` Then you can do

```
var task1 = callasync1();
var task2 = callasync2();
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new []{task1, task2}, (antecedents) => stopprogressindicator());
```

Answer (score 1):

I do like the idea of using `Task` API, but in this case you may simply use a counter:

```
int _asyncCalls = 0;

Constructor()
{
   startprogressindicator();

   Interlocked.Increment(ref _asyncCalls);
   try
   {
       // better yet, do Interlocked.Increment(ref _asyncCalls) inside
       // each callasyncN

       Interlocked.Increment(ref _asyncCalls);
       callasync1(finished1);

       Interlocked.Increment(ref _asyncCalls);
       callasync2(finished2);

       //.... and so on
   }
   finally
   {       
       checkStopProgreessIndicator();
   }
}

public checkStopProgreessIndicator()
{
   if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref _asyncCalls) == 0)
       stopprogressindicator();
}

public void finished1()
{
    checkStopProgreessIndicator()
}

public void finished2()
{
    checkStopProgreessIndicator()
}
```